# Create two partitions that share the total disk space

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, boot-partition

I like having two partitions `C:` (the boot partition) and `D:` on my main drive for organizational purposes: all windows data and programs are in `C:` and my projects and data are in `D:`. However I don't like the fact that I need to choose the partition sizes. I would like it to be dynamic/transparent. I want to be able to be able to contain as much data as needed in either `C:` or `D:`, as long as the total used space is less than the disk space of course.

Example: an 1 TB SSD.

- start with 200 GB used in `C:` and 200 GB used in `D:`
- continue with 300 GB in `C:` and 600 GB in `D:`
- continue with 600 GB in `C:` and 300 GB in `D:`
- continue with 300 GB in `C:` and 600 GB in `D:`

Basically `C:` and `D:` should behave as the 2 top level folders in a single partition.

All of this should be possible without me needing to manually resize the partitions. I also don't like the idea of a software automatically resizing the partitions because of the resize impact on the disk (*).

I know that this is not possible with standard partitions. But maybe there is a solution that uses something else (a layer on top of standard partitions maybe). I looked into Windows Dynamic disks but that seems to be about combining multiple disks, not what I need.

I don't care if `C:` and `D:` are somehow just links to 2 top level folders in a single partition as long as:

- windows can **boot** from `C:`
- all the programs work as expected with `C:` and `D:` as roots
- in Explorer `C:` and `D:` appear as two drives.

---

(*) by "impact on disk" I mean that shrinking a partition involves moving data around to make space on the end of the partition.

Comment: What is the difference between what you want and 2 folders in the root of that drive?

Comment: @Gantendo C: is the boot partition. I can do what you suggest on disks that are not the boot disk, but cannot do it on the boot disk.

Comment: You need a Mac ;)) APFS volumes are completely flexible. Their size is just shared. No user intervention required. TBH, you're not really using NTFS partitions effectively, trying to separate your activity as you are. The drive fails, you lose it all anyway. There's no substitute for a backup.

Comment: Changing drive partitions is, at best, a  **s l o w**  and **risky** process. What you ask is equivalent to stating, "when my car reaches 50 km/h, I'll open up the gearbox, take out the two gears for first speed and reinstall two gears for second." Until a different file system is invented, that is not practical.

Comment: @Tetsujin this is not about backup nor about redundancy. This is about data organization.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I stated I don't want to automatically change partitions when space is full. I want a 1 time setup that works as expected without further changing partitions specifically because of the strain on the disk a resize would involve.. I can accept that the file system does not allow this. But as user experience I don't see how what I want is unreasonable.

Comment: To the downvoters: can you please tell how I can improve the question?

Comment: Partitioning means blicking off into seperate areas.  By definition what you want is not possible.  There are some partial workarrounds but none that match your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Partitions on a disk are fixed, unless you wish to stop and re-partition. It certainly is not dynamic.

A better approach I think is to have major folder structures and keep data under two or three major structures.

I have virtual machines, a 1 TB drive, and do myself as I suggest to you. Data storage this way is naturally dynamic.

Here is a good screenshot of completely dynamic disk storage

[image: Disk Setup]

.

I recently moved about 100 GB from the upper drive to the lower right drive partly to balance usage and partly to permit space to spin up new drives.  Works splendidly well.

Comment: This is not possible because the disk contains the boot partition. I cannot have windows installed in a folder I create instead of on the root partition.

Comment: If you want a dynamic process then I suggest you start again with 1 large partition. What you want is not available any other practical way.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is not new, and is even common on Linux systems. The most popular implementation is a file system called [btrfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs) and its core concept - **subvolumes**.

Subvolumes are mountable just like other partitions, but share the same disk space on one single btrfs partition.

In easy words:

- btrfs is a file system (works similar to NTFS from user perspective) which a partition is made of,
- subvolume is abstracted on top of such partition as a *folder*.

The advantage comes from the ability to mount subvolume just like `C:` or `D:` drive, at the OS level.
Btrfs has many other valuable features, but so if it for Linux only?

With help comes [WinBtrfs](https://github.com/maharmstone/btrfs) - free, opens source, completely unlinked with Linux kernel, written from scratch signed **driver**. GitHub README shows that exist an implementation of a bootloader supporting btrfs. This means it is theoretical possible to have `C:` and `D:` drives occupying the same physical space.

Unfortunately, didn't test it enough. When I've tried installing Win11 and load driver before partitioning, the installer couldn't recognize the file as a driver. So it's more tricky. [Here interesting thread](https://github.com/maharmstone/btrfs/issues/16) describing successful booting of Windows from C: btrfs drive.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).